# Запустить программу в отдельном потоке

Tags: python

У меня есть программа, которая запускает несколько сотен одновременных потоков:

```
for i in range(len(ips)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=request, args=(i,))
        t.start()
```

И когда запускаются эти потоки и работают какое-то время, то при попытке закрыть программу комбинацией **ctrl+c** программа не закрывается, а вбрасывается исключение `Keyboard Interrupt`. Как это исправить? Создавать отдельный поток и запускать внутри него основную программу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы ваши потоки остановились при прерывании главного потока нужно у каждого потока установить атрибут `daemon` в True.

Пример как это работает:

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def loop():
    while True:
        # делаем какую-то работу
        time.sleep(0.05)


for _ in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=loop)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stop script")
```

Однако это может приводит к неверному освобождению ресурсов.
Поэтому лучше всего будет воспользоваться каким-либо механизмом, который скажет потокам что им нужно прекратить свое выполнение. Например `Event`:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

ex = Event()


def loop():
    while not ex.is_set():
        time.sleep(0.05)
    print("Stop thread")


threads = []
for _ in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=loop)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ex.set()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print("Stop script")
```

Все должно работать и в случае если потоки запускаются в функции:

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

ex = Event()


def loop():
    while not ex.is_set():
        time.sleep(0.05)
    print("Stop thread")


def start_threads():
    threads = []
    for _ in range(10):
        t = Thread(target=loop)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.05)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ex.set()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print("Stop script")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_threads()
```

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы используете `time.sleep(0.05)`? Это ведь настолько малое значение.

Comment: В функции loop я использовал sleep просто для эмуляции какой-либо работы.

Comment: А в цикле ожидания, в главном потоке, небольшая задержка нужна для того, чтобы не нагружать процессор лишней работой.

Comment: а что делать, если потоки запускаются в теле функции? Если запустить все потоки и после цикла вставить `while True: time.sleep(0.05)`, то при нажатии Ctrl+C возникает другое KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Приведите код, так как даже если все обернуть в функцию, результат будет точно таким же. Обновил ответ, у вас такой случай?

Comment: @да, именно так. Спасибо.

Comment: Хм, если `while` уже запущен и внутри него что-то происходит, то при нажатии кнопки поток не остановится, а будет ждать, пока происходящее в цикле не завершится. Можно ли как-то вызвать break в теле `while`?

Comment: Да конечно, если у вас что-то блокирует поток, то тут уже ничего не сделать. Если вы делаете request'ы, то для них можно установить таймауты, тогда у вас поток будет `заморожен` максимум на значение таймаута, и после таймату будет остановлен.