# Поток перестаёт работать, если установлен флаг daemon = True

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал программу, в которой есть функция, в теле которой раз за разом воспроизводится `while loop`([используемый мной алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666452/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5/666533#666533)) и программу можно остановить только по нажатию кнопки. Но почему-то, при использовании `t.daemon = True` программа не выполняется, а просто закрывается спустя 3-4 секунды после запуска.

Документация Python гласит(о daemon):

> A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon = False.

**Вопрос:** почему и как флаг `daemon = True` останавливает выполнение программы? Или потоки в ней?

Comment: Код покажите. Я на 100% процентов уверен что вы неправильно ждете завершения потоков

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с проблемой. Это связано с тем, что основной поток, из которого запускаются демон-потоки, не является демон-потоком. И вот когда все демон-потоки запущены, в основной программе ничего не происходит и ей просто нечего делать. Потому-то она и закрывается. Как вариант решения этой проблемы можно использовать:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```